# Display items inside ScrollView on Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, scrollview

My problem is when i want to display multiple items inside a scrollview on Storyboard, i can't scroll to add more items because of the screen size of the View Controller. How can i get around this ?

Xcode version : 4.6
Autolayout : enabled

Here is what i want to do :

[image: Example]

EDIT : I found a workaround to this problem. Just add items with minimal height and then resize it in code.

Comment: You can Add `SubView` Programmatically in your code ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in code. [view addSubview: anotherView]

Comment: Yes it's sure that i can add it in code, but it could be simple to do it from the storyboard.

Comment: I worked around this in one project by creating a custom UIStoryboardSegue implementation which essentially embedded another UIViewControllers view into a UIScrollView. It's a bit on the heavy side but if you have a complex view you really want define in your storyboard rather than with code and present it through a UIScrollView it works.

Comment: It all depends on how many views you want to add to your scroll view and how big they will be.

Comment: @MarcinKuptel i have to add 2 UICollectionViews

Comment: Is it wise to add UICollectionViews which are themselves UIScrollViews to a UIScrollView?

Comment: What are the bounds of the collection views & scroll view how do you intend the scrolling to work?

Comment: @MikePollard The scroll will be horizontally

Comment: Given that you're talking about having a UIScrollView and 2 UICollectionViews I'm not sure 'The scroll will be horizontally' really gives us enough information to help.

Comment: But the problem here is not the scrollview, it's adding items inside storyboard ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way. Might seem difficult but its actually quite easy. It's a hybrid solution, with storyboard and nib file. You have to build a view inside a nib file instead of a storyboard.

1) Create your view controller named, let's say, "MyViewController".

2) Create a nib file, named "MyViewController" (name of a viewcontroller and nib file must match for this trick to work).

3) Go to that nib file, you created, drag a scroll view from object library.

4) Look at the side menu, and search for "File's Owner" icon (empty
cube), Under identity inspector Change the file's owner to the view
controller you created, "MyViewController".

5) Right click on the file owner and a menu will pop up, control drag, from the view connection to the scroll view you dragged from object library.

6) Click on the scroll view you just dragged, and go to the attributes inspector.
Under "Simulated Metrics" change "Size" from "Retina 4 Full Screen",
or whatever it happens to be, to "Freedom".Now you can drag bottom
edge of the scroll view down, to make enough room for all the
subviews. Make sure you don't accidentally increase the width.

7) Go back to the storyboard.

8) If the view controller is not created, drag it from the objects library. 
Change its class to "MyViewController".

9) Now this is where the trick is gonna happen.
Make sure you delete ALL views from that view controller, including
the background view. If you do that correctly you will be able to see
the grid background of the interface builder. This forces the
storyboard to look for a nib named the same as the view controller.

10) Run, and smile (Make sure that you add some subviews to the scroll
view, that are off the bounds of a single screen, so you must scroll
to see them, otherwise it wont set the contentSize correctly, and you
wont be able to scroll ) :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to beloved steps

[image: Change size of ViewController Size]

[image: Change Size of View of ViewController]

[image: Add button]

after add button resize of view(height=568) and Viewcontroller > Simulated Metrics > Size >  inferred

Answer (score 1):

make scrollview object and set in viewDidLoad .

`self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 960);`

Use what height you want like: 960

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a very practical way to do it in IB. A better approach would be to do it in code.